# Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' when trying to select from database while using letters

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to select a value from the database, it works perfectly if everything is just numbers - but fails to work if there are letters involved. This is in OpenCart.

My column is called `campaign_code` , its type is `VARCHAR`.

Here is the command...

```
$campaign_id = $this->db->query("SELECT campaign_id FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "campaign WHERE campaign_code = ". $this->db->escape($campaign_code));
```

When `$campaign_code` equals any number it's fine. It selects as expected.

When its letters or a combination of numbers or letters I get this error...

```
Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Error: Unknown column '85f' in 'where clause'&lt;br /&gt;Error No: 1054&lt;br /&gt;SELECT campaign_id FROM oc_campaign WHERE campaign_code = 85f' in C:\xampp\htdocs\microcharity\system\database\mysqli.php:40
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using an `integer` in `where clause`, you can avoid `quotes` but while using a string you have to enclose it in single quotes.

For integer -

```
$campaign_id = $this->db->query("SELECT campaign_id FROM '".DB_PREFIX."' WHERE campaign_code = ".$this->db->escape($campaign_code)."");
```

For string -

```
$campaign_id = $this->db->query("SELECT campaign_id FROM '".DB_PREFIX."' WHERE campaign_code = '".$this->db->escape($campaign_code)."'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost answer your own question by providing all the details.

Yes, when you provide `WHERE col = 1` it interprets `1` as integer, an searches for this integer. When you provide `WHERE col = something` it searches for column something i.e. `WHERE id = id2` (this is used when you want the results where the values from one column are equal to other column). If you want to search with strings, you need quotes like `WHERE col = 'you string'`

If you google your exception, you might find the answer `unknown column in where clause`

[MySQL: Unknown column in where clause error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480327/mysql-unknown-column-in-where-clause-error)